# Is it possible to make a Codedeploy BlueGreen deployment to ECS use healthcheck data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

I haven't been able to do this. I have healthchecks configured on my NLB's two target groups and they report healthy, but the deployment will take place and succeed even if the target group that is being switched to never becomes healthy.

I can use alarms and lambda based tests to rollback of course, but I'm not sure if I can create an alarm that targets the currently non-serving-prod target group and not the currently serving-prod one in order to rollback the deployment properly.

It seems that it's not possible to use anything but CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce for an ECS green/blue, and I also see that its not possible at all to define minimum healthy hosts in ECS deployment configurations, so does this mean that CodeDeploy doesn't consider health status at all when deploying ECS?

Here's my codedeploy terraform:

```
resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "deployment_group" {
  app_name               = aws_codedeploy_app.application.name
  deployment_group_name  = "${var.project_name}-deployment-group"
  service_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.codedeploy_role.arn
  deployment_config_name = "CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce"

  # Automatically rollback on failure, alarm, or request.
  # See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/APIReference/API_AutoRollbackConfiguration.html
  auto_rollback_configuration {
    enabled = "true"
    events = ["DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE", "DEPLOYMENT_STOP_ON_ALARM", "DEPLOYMENT_STOP_ON_REQUEST"]
  }

  blue_green_deployment_config {
    # See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/APIReference/API_DeploymentReadyOption.html
    deployment_ready_option {
      action_on_timeout = "CONTINUE_DEPLOYMENT"
    }

    terminate_blue_instances_on_deployment_success {
      action = "TERMINATE"

      # How many minutes to wait before terminating old instances
      termination_wait_time_in_minutes = 1
    }
  }

  # These settings are required for ECS deployments.
  deployment_style {
    deployment_option = "WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL"
    deployment_type   = "BLUE_GREEN"
  }

  # What to deploy
  ecs_service {
    cluster_name = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name
    service_name = aws_ecs_service.service.name
  }

  load_balancer_info {
    target_group_pair_info {
      # The path used by a load balancer to route production traffic when an Amazon ECS deployment is complete.
      prod_traffic_route {
        listener_arns = [aws_lb_listener.listener.arn]
      }

      # Blue group is the original group at first.
      target_group {
        name = aws_lb_target_group.blue_group.name
      }

      # Green group is the one that gets switched to at first.
      target_group {
        name = aws_lb_target_group.green_group.name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my target groups:

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "blue_group" {
  name        = "${var.project_name}-${var.stage}-b"
  port        = 8080
  protocol    = "TCP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  health_check {
      path = var.nlb_healthcheck_path
      port = var.container_port
      protocol = "HTTP"
      healthy_threshold = 2
      unhealthy_threshold = 2
      interval = 10
   }

  stickiness {
      enabled = false
      type = "lb_cookie"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "green_group" {
  name        = "${var.project_name}-${var.stage}-g"
  port        = 8080
  protocol    = "TCP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  health_check {
      path = aws_lb_target_group.blue_group.health_check[0].path
      port = aws_lb_target_group.blue_group.health_check[0].port
      protocol = aws_lb_target_group.blue_group.health_check[0].protocol
      healthy_threshold = aws_lb_target_group.blue_group.health_check[0].healthy_threshold
      unhealthy_threshold = aws_lb_target_group.blue_group.health_check[0].unhealthy_threshold
      interval = aws_lb_target_group.blue_group.health_check[0].interval
   }

  stickiness {
      enabled = false
      type = "lb_cookie"
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you can't.

Comment: It seems that the install phase does different things depending on the ELB health status. On initial status it will wait, on unhealthy it will wait and ecs will restart the container, but on unused or healthy status it will proceed. The waiting phase after the traffic rerouting does automatically use health status to stop and rollback but during the install phase it will simply wait possibly forever. The only way in a blue green deploy for the green group to be in initial or healthy status rather than unused during the install phase is to attach an additional listener so it always serves.